# A question about non-criminal record for Canadian work-permit

Tags: paperwork, criminal-records

I am applying for a Canadian work permit from Pakistan. I stayed in China and have to provide a non-criminal record from China as well.

The question I want to ask is that I let China 40 days after getting my non-criminal certificate (all my stay was fully legal)? Hence, technically those later 40-days are not covered for my non-criminal record. Is it fine or do I need a new record of non-criminal certificate after I have left China?

Comment: This fits better on Expatriates.SE. When did you stay in China and for how long?

Comment: I stayed for nearly 19 months. from Oct 2019 till May 2021. I received my China's non-criminal record on 26th March.

Comment: It's probably fine. The Canadian officials should understand that if you *were* convicted of criminal activity in China during those 40 days, you would not have been permitted to leave China at all.